# How can I #include a file whose name is built up from a macro?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

On a cross-platform project, I want to #include a header file whose name contains the name of the platform. I have a #define macro for the platform.

So for example, for

```
#define PLATFORM win32
```

I want

```
#include "engine\win32\devices_win32.h"
```

while for

```
#define PLATFORM linux
```

I want

```
#include "engine\linux\devices_linux.h"
```

---

I'm going with Richard Pennington's answer, minus one line of code - it works for me!

```
#define PLATFORM Linux
#define xstr(x) #x
#define str(x) xstr(x)
#define sub(x) x
#include str(sub(engine/PLATFORM/devices_)PLATFORM.h)
```

Comment: Not sure but try: #include "engine\" PLATFORM "\devices_" PLATFORM ".h"

Comment: Not an answer to the macro portion, but I usually have something like "win32/engine/devices.h" and "linux/engine/devices.h".  I use '#include "engine/devices.h"' in my code, and then set the include path properly in the makefile for the platform I want to compile against (-Iwin32 or -Ilinux).

Comment: @cjhuitt - that's a nice solution, but unfortunately I'm working in the constraint that a lot of the files have already been laid out "system\platform" rather than "platform\system" and I don't think the rest of the team would appreciate me reworking the folder layouts!

Comment: @cjhuitt - also - my base class is already named devices.h - my platform specific code lives in derived classes in files named with the described convention e.g. devices_win32.h - it just help to have uniquely named files (e.g. with visual assist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define PLATFORM Linux
#define xstr(x) #x
#define str(x) xstr(x)
#define sub(x) x
#define FILE str(sub(engine/PLATFORM/devices_)PLATFORM.h)

#include FILE
```

I'm not sure I'd use it, though. ;-)
I had to use Linux rather than linux because linux is defined as 1 in my compiler.

Comment: I tried this on gcc, and it actually works. I'm surprised, because the C++ standard seems to say this shouldn't work. 16.3.7 reads `"If a # preprocessing token, followed by an identifier, occurs lexically at the point in which a preprocessing directive could begin, the identifier is not subject to macro replacement."` The way I read that, an #include directive would not be subject to macro replacement. But apparently it works, so either I'm misunderstanding what the standard says, or gcc is violating the standard. (Most likely the former.)

Comment: Charles, it works with my preprocessor also, which is based on the one used by clang. I think it is standard C.

Comment: The rule you quote forbids changing #define foo include ... #foo.

Comment: @Charles:The relevant part of the standard for this is §16.2/4.

Comment: @Jerry, you're right.  Well, I'm upvoting this because it does exactly what the OP wants, even though it's ugly.

Comment: works without the #define FILE... step which is exactly what I want - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Usually, you would do something more like:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include "devices_win32.h"
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
#include "devices_linux.h"
#endif
```

...rather than having a single `PLATFORM` definition which can be set differently depending on the platform.

Comment: This way is much better than the computed include, because it is standardly used and every reader of the code immediatelly knows what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well in practice, this could be achieved using something like

```
#define PLATFORM win32

#define INCLUDE_FILE devices_ ## PLATFORM

#define QUOTED_INCLUDE_FILE #INCLUDE_FILE

#include QUOTED_INCLUDE_FILE
```

but the the following rule would prevent you from doing this:

> C comments and predefined macro names are not recognized inside a `#include' directive in which the file name is delimited with` <' and `>'.
>
> C comments and predefined macro names are never recognized within a character or string constant. (Strictly speaking, this is the rule, not an exception, but it is worth noting here anyway.)

Comment: Do you have a source for the rule you quoted? It doesn't seem to match the rules in the C++ (or C) standard.

Comment: This is a quote from the GCC documentation available at:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html. Chapter 1 "The C Proprocessor" section 1 "Transformations Made Globally"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can only use the stringify operator on macro arguments, so your example won't work. (In other words, `#define foo(bar) #bar` is allowed, but `#define foo #bar` is not, even if bar is a macro.)